# TypeScript how to discriminate type aliases which refer to the same type

Tags: typescript

For example, when I write:

```
type Email = string
type Password = string

const returnsEmail = (): Email => 'email@example.com' as Email
const returnsPassword = (): Password => 'P4ssw0rd' as Password

const email1: Email = 'email@example.com' // OK
const email2: Email = returnsEmail() // OK
const email3: Email = returnsPassword() // should not be OK but silent
```

TypeScript 2.8.3 seems to emit no errors here. Is this intended behaviour? TypeScript's "aliases" are just "macros"? I know TypeScript deals with only static typing and not validation (kinds of regex matching, in the case like above), but I think this is the bussiness for the former and should be done, especially if annotations explicitly written.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes this is intended behaviour, type alias is called 'alias' precisely for that reason - it does not create a new distinct type.

Also, you probably will be surprised, but in TypeScript two different **types** are interchangeable if they have the same definition, it's called [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html):

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
}

interface Pet {
    name: string;
}

const p: Pet = {name: 'Rosie'};

const person: Person = p; // no error
```

For the time being (until nominal types are added to TypeScript), one has to resort to various tricks to make types artificially incompatible. One such trick is called '[branded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4895#issuecomment-142428454)' ([example here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/types.ts#L52)), it works by adding superficial property to the type which is never used in the code, it serves only to make the type incompatible to anything else:

```
type Email = string & { __emailBrand: any };
type Password = string & { __passwordBrand: any };

const returnsEmail = (): Email => 'email@example.com' as Email
const returnsPassword = (): Password => 'P4ssw0rd' as Password

const email1: Email = 'email@example.com' as Email;//has to use type assertion here
const email2: Email = returnsEmail() // OK
const email3: Email = returnsPassword() // error
```

Comment: Oh pretty hacky but works... and I also didn't know the term "nominal types"  Thanks

Comment: No one was using the term "nominal types" when all type systems in practical use were nominal, structural typing was an obscure and long forgotten concept until TypeScript came about.

Comment: Coming here to say Thank You for this great response!

Comment: Another relevant link in The TypeScript FAQ: [Can I make a type alias nominal?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal)